# why use "static" keyword before public data member?

Tags: c++

I have an integer data member called "students" in public part of my class and is used as an argument in the constructor.
gradebook.h:

```
class gradebook
{
public:
    int students = 10;
    gradebook(string, int[]);
    void SetCourseName(string _coursename);
    ...
private:
    string coursename;
    ...
};
```

gradebook.cpp:

```
#include "gradebook.h"

gradebook::gradebook(string s1, int array[students])
{
    SetCourseName(s1);
}
void gradebook::SetCourseName(string _coursename)
{
    coursename = _coursename;
}
```

when I try to compile the code receive this error:

```
invalid use of non-static data member 'gradebook::students'
gradebook::gradebook(string s1, int array[students])
                                          ^
```

if I put 'static const' before 'int student = 10' the problem gets away.

why?

Comment: You need to use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression defines a stack-allocated array of a fixed length. The length of the array must be known at compile time:

```
int array[students]
```

adding the `static` keyword inlines the length of the array as a compile-time constant.

To allow in-class initialization as in your example you actually need to define the variable const and static as follows:

```
static const int students = 10;
```

You could find some details on arrays here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Addition: passing an array of fixed length as a parameter results in passing a pointer, the length is ignored. Therefore, you could simply omit the "length" of the passed array and use your in-class variable as a constant for iterating through the array.

Comment: This results in a code as if we were writing `int array[]` or `int * array`. But syntactically the variable is used to initialize an array of the certain length. In modern C++ nothing prevents you from initializing a non-static integral variable inside the class definition. Just in this specific context it does not work out.